# Combinations of numbers with weight

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I have an array / list of numbers. Each number has a certain priority / importance.

I need an algorithm that generate all combinations of numbers, but begin form numbers with the most importance.

```
e.g. [number, priority]: [1,1], [2,3], [3,2]. Highest priority is 1.
```

Combinations:

```
1, 3, 2, 1 1, 1 3, 3 3, 3 1, 1 2, 3 2, 2 1, 2 2, 1 1 1, 1 1 3, 1 3 1...
```

Any idea how to do this?
Of course, I want to generate a certain number of combinations.

Comment: Do you have code that produces simple permutations? If so, what modifications did you try? If not, do that and then update the question.

Comment: I do not have the code because I tried to create a pseudocode whole algorithm

Comment: What do you want? This is not at all clear. I guess `1, 3, 2` are your original numbers, sorted wrt. priority? But then what is `1 3`? Do you really mean combinations, not permutations?

Comment: Improved post. I mean all the combinations with repetition. My mistake

Comment: How many repetitions? Is (1,1,1,1) a valid result? How is it ordered, compared with (1,1,1)?

Comment: Best option would by method with two params: last combination and number of next combinations. But right now i have absolutly no idea, how to do this.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: It's reference how to create permiations, to use permuations with priorities, just sort pairs before permutation run

Comment: The question is underspecified. You don't know yourself what you really want.

Comment: Take a look at my [answer][1] to this question:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12605600/643828

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my answer to an example code, this way you don't even need a recursion. You have to sort first the elements by the priority. The example is in Perl, which is not so far from Pseudocode

```
@numbers = (1, 3, 2, 4);

push(@result, @numbers);
push(@working_list, @numbers);
for ($i = 1; $i < @numbers; $i++) {  # We loop exactly for the length of the array (-1 because the first iteration is already inside)
    my @result_list;
    for $result (@working_list) { # get the result of the last iteration of $i
        for $number (@numbers) { # iterate the numbers
            push (@result_list, "$result $number");  # adding the numbers
        }
    }

    push(@result, @result_list); # push the last result to final result list
    undef @working_list;
    push(@working_list, @result_list); # use the last result as a start point for next $i iteration

}

print join(', ', @result);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for all combinations not for all permutations(I do not see any set of numbers repeated so you only care about the set of numbers but not of the order within that set).

Here is a tip for you - first write down the code that will produce all the possible combinations of the numbers 1 to n and then do a simple bijection between those number and the ones you are given taking into account the weights.

Comment: His example contains (1 3) and (3 1), so he clearly makes a distinction in the sequence of the numbers. You could try to argue that the first number is n, and the second the priority, but then you wouldn't have (1 1) and (1 3). Imho the question is underspecified and can't be answered in the current state.